# Ansible nested loop cross list reference?

Tags: loops, nested-loops, ansible

I'm trying to solve this and frankly I'm beggining to think it doesn't work that way.

```
- name: Create directories
  file:
    path: "{{ item[0] }}"
    state: directory
    owner: some_user
    group: some_group
    mode: some_mode
  with_nested:
     - [ '/var/lib/{{ item[1] }}', '/var/lib/{{ item[1] }}/conf' ]
     - [ 'app1', 'app2' ]
```

Apparently there's a scope issue here, I'm just not getting it.

If it's not clear enough, I want to create the app dirs first and then conf dirs inside each of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create directories you need just one loop:

```
- name: Create directories
  file:
    path: "/var/lib/{{ item }}/conf"
    state: directory
  with_items:
     - app1
     - app2
```

From [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718125136/http://docs.ansible.com:80/ansible/file_module.html):

> If `state=directory`, all immediate subdirectories will be created if they do not exist, since 1.7 they will be created with the supplied permissions

**Update**: in case of multiple subfolders (conf, logs, etc):

```
- name: Create directories
  file:
    path: "/var/lib/{{ item[1] }}/{{ item[0] }}"
    state: directory
  with_nested: 
     - [ 'conf', 'logs' ]
     - [ 'app1', 'app2' ]
```

Comment: @CyborgWombat i've updated the answer. In any case you can't do dependent items in nested loop (item[1] dependent on item[0]), you always need to find a way around...

Comment: Please add link to docs into your answer: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html

Comment: Yeah. I figured that out already, so I've deleted my comment.
Thanks so much, @KonstantinSuvorov :)